# GPU has fallen off the bus

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda

After I added additional Nvidia 1080ti and run training neural network, I got such error.

```
GPU 0000:0a:00.0: GPU has fallen off the bus.
```

After rebooting, I can't run neither `nvidia-smi` command, nor `nvidia-bug-report.sh`. Both of them don't assert any errors, but also don't do anything. Also I can't kill this process via classic ctrl+C.
Also running `torch.cuda.is_available()` from python just freezes process: no error, no output.
So not, after that error none of my videocards is working, so I have no idea what to check.

PS

`lshw` shows all 3 displays properly

Comment: ```GPU has fallen off the bus``` is possibly because of power failure or a damage to the GPU.But also it might be a bug within the driver.Have you tried using a newer driver if possible ?

Comment: yes, possibly because of power, but now I can't run `nvidia-smi` or anything. So my problem is not in crash, but in that AFTER crash, everything fails